# Using Poisson distribution to win a bet that a theater wont be N% full by the time the movie starts

Tags: probability-distributions

Then just from a brute force computation, I found that the largest value of $N$ needs to be 99 since any value greater than 99 is greater than 0.5. Is that correct? or is there another way to solve without brute force computation?

Comment: What is $L$?  Where did you get the first equation?  Note that the expected number of people there is $102$ so you should expect the theater to be close to full and $N$ should be larger.

Comment: sorry $L$ is the lambda value.

Comment: the total capacity of the theater is 100, how can the expected number of people be 100

Comment: 5/min times 20 min.  That does not depend on the capacity.  If the capacity isn't large enough, some will be turned away

Comment: @RossMillikan oh okay, so what part should I adjust?

Comment: $\lambda = 100$

Comment: @RossMillikan ah okay so I just redid the calculation in my original post and got $N\leq 99%$ Does that make sense? it seems like too high of a value for $N$.

Comment: As I said in my first comment the theater should be close to full.  I didn't check the details, but that sounds right.  For high $\lambda$ the Poisson distribution becomes normal, so you would expect the $50$th percentile to be just about the expected number.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah okay thanks, I see what you're saying. I guess I was just confused because I think it means that the friend loses no matter what? or if N was that big, then the friend shouldn't make the bet because the probability of him winning is less than 0.5 for almost anything he can guess

Comment: I think that is correct.